# Revised Ranger: Does Natural Explorer grant Sneak attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, unearthed-arcana

This question is about the Revised Ranger from Unearthed Arcana, not the one from the PHB.

In the new Natural Explorer feat for the Revised Ranger it says

> On    your    first   turn    during  combat, you have advantage  on  attack
>   rolls against creatures that  have    not yet acted.

That means apparently that you always have advantage at your first turn against everyone you beat in the Initiative order.

But what if you multi-class with rogue and have access to Sneak Attack? Would the advantage from Natural Explorer trigger Sneak Attack?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: A reminder that [Unearthed Arcana is NOT tuned for multiclassing](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/841465335828041729)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

As long as you have not yet used your sneak attack on the same turn and have an eligible weapon (light or ranged), having advantage on an attack roll against a creature allows you to make a sneak attack upon hit. The source of the advantage does not matter.

Note that the rogue archetype Assassin (PHB, page 97) has a similar but not identical ability, *Assassinate*, at level 3:

> You have advantage on attack rolls against any creature that hasn't taken a turn in the combat yet. In addition, any hit you score against a creature that is surprised is a critical hit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the additional information! Seems like going Assassin would be redundant if you already have Revised Ranger levels, so I'll probably go for another archetype.